# Having Different Buttons to play Videos using Youtube API

Tags: java, android

I am working on an App and what I want to get it to do is that whenever a button is clicked a video is played based on the requirements of the button. I also want to specify a playlist of youtube videos so that whenever the button is clicked it will choose a random video from the playlist. I am doing this app in android studios but I am having trouble implementing this. Any ideas would be a great help. So far I only have it so that when I click the happy button for example it o plays the playlist but when I tried to implement the other buttons the same way the app keeps on crashing. I will paste the code down below.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 
View.OnClickListener{

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    Button button0 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.HappyButton);
    Button button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.SadButton);
    Button button2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MellowButton);
    Button button3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.MotivatedButton);
    Button button4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.AngryButton);


    button0.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            openHappy();
        }
    });

    button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,this,YoutubeSad.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

I have also pasted the code for the `youtube_activity`

```
public class YoutubeActivity extends YouTubeBaseActivity
          implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener  {

    private static final String TAG = "YoutubeActivity";
    static final String  GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDMS4J2hlSJqCZsNL1Owqcups91vGQiF3I";
    static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO = "d-diB65scQU";
    static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST = "RDQMhH0aPyrY-R0";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

    ConstraintLayout mylayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_youtube,null);
    setContentView(mylayout);

    YouTubePlayerView playerView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
    playerView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mylayout.addView(playerView);
    playerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY,this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess: provider is " + provider.getClass().toString() );
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Initliazed youtube player succesfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // Now we are using the Event Listener and the StateChange Listener
    //youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
    //youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);



    if(!wasRestored){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO);
    }


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    if(youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){
        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this,REQUEST_CODE).show();
    }else{
        String errorMessage = String.format("There was an error initialiazing youtube player (%1$s)", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }


}


//        private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = 
new YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
////        @Override
////        public void onPlaying() {
////            Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this, "Good, video is playing 
ok", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////
 ////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onPaused() {
////            Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this, "Good, video is paused", 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onStopped() {
////            Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"Video has been stopped" , 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////
////
////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onBuffering(boolean b) {
////
////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onSeekTo(int i) {
////
////        }
 ////    };
////
////    private YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener 
playerStateChangeListener = new YouTubePlayer.PlayerStateChangeListener() {
////        @Override
////        public void onLoading() {
 ////
////        }
////
////        @Override
 ////        public void onLoaded(String s) {
////
////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onAdStarted() {
////            Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"Click Ad now, make me rich" , 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////
////
////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onVideoStarted() {
////            Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"Video has started" , 
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////
////
////        }
////
////        @Override
////        public void onVideoEnded() {
////            Toast.makeText(YoutubeActivity.this,"You have reached the end of 
the video" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
////
////
////        }
//
//        @Override
//        public void onError(YouTubePlayer.ErrorReason errorReason) {
//
//        }
//    };
}
```

This is the `YoutubeSad` code

```
public class YoutubeSad extends  YouTubeBaseActivity implements 
YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener{

private static final String TAG = "YoutubeActivity";
static final String  GOOGLE_API_KEY = "AIzaSyDMS4J2hlSJqCZsNL1Owqcups91vGQiF3I";
static final String YOUTUBE_VIDEO = "BZsXcc_tC-o";
static final String YOUTUBE_PLAYLIST = "RDQM6VDEVrfYua8";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_youtube);

    ConstraintLayout mylayout = (ConstraintLayout) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.activity_youtube,null);
    setContentView(mylayout);

    YouTubePlayerView playerView = new YouTubePlayerView(this);
    playerView.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
    mylayout.addView(playerView);
    playerView.initialize(GOOGLE_API_KEY,this);
}

@Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {

    Log.d(TAG, "onInitializationSuccess: provider is " + provider.getClass().toString() );
    //Toast.makeText(this,"Initliazed youtube player succesfully" , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


    // Now we are using the Event Listener and the StateChange Listener
    //youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
    //youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);



    if(!wasRestored){
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(YOUTUBE_VIDEO);
    }


}

@Override
public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult youTubeInitializationResult) {

    final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;

    if(youTubeInitializationResult.isUserRecoverableError()){
        youTubeInitializationResult.getErrorDialog(this,REQUEST_CODE).show();
    }else{
        String errorMessage = String.format("There was an error initialiazing youtube player (%1$s)", youTubeInitializationResult.toString());
        Toast.makeText(this,errorMessage,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }


    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this,this,YoutubeSad.class);
```

to this

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YoutubeSad.class);
```

Comment: Okay, is YoutubeSad your own class? THen please add the code. And also please tell me when the error occurs(e.g. after clicking Button1) Also you said you implemented the other Buttons the same way, but you are calling another activity there, so I do not really know what you want to do there.

Comment: And when does the error occurs? Also the error message would be nice.

Comment: I used the same code for the from the YoutubeActivity for the YoutubeSad. And when I click my second button that should be connected to YoutubeSad the app just closes

Comment: This is what the logcat says                                                                          03-24 11:13:42.476 1484-26835/? E/AudioFlinger: createRecordTrack_l() initCheck failed -12; no control block?
03-24 11:13:42.476 2269-17446/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: AudioFlinger could not create record track, status: -12
03-24 11:13:42.478 2269-17446/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -12.

Comment: Perfect, I edited my answer please try my new answer

Comment: what did you change exactly because its still crashing

Comment: Replaced  this, this with MainActivity.this

Comment: I'm sorry I don't see the changes can you maybe try again and then i will try it out.

Comment: Try changing

Intent intent = new Intent(this,this,YoutubeSad.class);
to this

Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,YoutubeSad.class);

Comment: Remove one this, and add MainActivity. for the other this

Comment: i have changed it and it still crashes my friend. I am really lost at this point and I want to finish this app if you can help.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167465/discussion-between-julien-100000-and-mohamed-ali).